# Linq-to-SQL: Update several stored procedures at once

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have a list of 158 stored procedures that need to be updated in the `.dbml` for my project. I work in a .NET shop that is using Linq-to-SQL. I am searching for a way to update my `.dbml` file with these stored procedures without doing the drag and drop one by one (using the ORM designer window).

Ideally, I would like to be able to update all 158 stored procedures in the `.dbml` file at one time - any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My bad, this is the first shop that I have been at that has used this technology - just EF, no linq to sql.  My coworker and I have found that updating the designer file is fairly easy, so I could go that route and avoid the dragging and dropping to the ORM window...but, is that best practice, I don't know...

Comment: Sorry - my bad - I didn't see that you mentioned the `.dbml` file - that's clearly Linq-to-SQL (and not Entity Framework)

Comment: You do know you can select more than one stored procedure at a time to drag, right?  So you can drag them all at once in one action...

Comment: I do, however selecting 158 out of thousands stored procedures to drag at one time is not ideal for me - I was hoping to find a better way, but no such luck...

Answer (score 0):

I honestly cannot see the issue. Using the designer is straightforward. Simply select all existing methods in the 'Methods Pane' on the right and delete them all. Then select all stored procedures from the 'Server Explorer' and drag and drop them to the methods pane again. Your dbml file will get regenerated.